# vvg2000 netgear multiple ips

Tags: networking, router

i'm connecting my office to the world with pppoe and netgear vvg2000 router.

this days i plug a web server for lcal testing and i want my clients to be able to see files on this webserver.

since i don't want my clients to surf to my office ip address, my isp attached another ip that leads to my office.

i tried to setup the "firewall rule" to lead port 80 to the internal ip of the server but that's not seems to work.

did i do something wrong?[image: my current settings]

Answer (score 2):

You have specified the rule to only allow 193.37.129.176 to be able to access port 80 and port 25 on 10.0.0.66.  More than likely, you'll need to leave the "wan users" blank unless you are restricting it intentionally.

Comment: feel dumbs now :) but yet, what i want to have is that only on ip will lead to port 80 while other ips won't